# No such file or directory found - git bash

Tags: file, github, git-bash, git-gui

error coming by cd filename

prakh@Prakhar11 MINGW64 ~ (main)
$ cd C:\Users\prakh\OneDrive\Desktop\github\my-github\src\app
bash: cd: C:UsersprakhOneDriveDesktopgithubmy-githubsrcapp: No such file or directory

trying to add file in github and push it

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the backslashes (`\`) with forward slashes (`/`):
and try this

```
cd /c/Users/prakh/OneDrive/Desktop/github/my-github/src/app
```

Also
The `/c/` at the beginning of the path is used in Git Bash to specify the `C:\` drive in Windows.

Also, ensure that the directory `app` exists under `C:\Users\prakh\OneDrive\Desktop\github\my-github\src\`. If you still get a "No such file or directory" error, the path might be wrong or the directory might not exist.